# How to identify a system with no overshoot in terms of poles?

Tags: control-theory, signal-processing

I'm trying to find a standard in order to identify a system with no overshoot in term of poles. I know that there is something related to dominant poles.
I was looking into a particular 4th-order system with the following poles:

```
   0.9155 + 0.0000i
  -0.7144 + 0.5750i
  -0.7144 - 0.5750i
  -0.2244 + 0.0000i
```

the system's response in the following:

[system's reponse and root locus graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCmml.png)

I want to know something like: systems with poles like that have this kind of response with no overshoot.
I was looking at other systems and I found that systems with positive and real poles have no overshoot, but it the case of the graph above has no overshoot too but has 2 real poles and a pair of complex poles.

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: Are you sure that it has no overshoot? What about modeling with a longer time interval and zooming in?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Zeekless . You are right, maybe there is overshoot, but far away. I modeled for 1000 samples and the overshoot is zero according to my calculation in Matlab. Maybe there is a way to recognize that kind of systems using something (maybe poles).

Comment: Maybe the answers to [this question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/9156) might help.

Comment: Thank @KwinvanderVeen for your comment but this is not what I'm looking for. I just need a way to identify when a system has no overshoot or its overshoot is found very far or something like that.

Comment: Do you know the fact that a linear system in *continuous time* has an overshoot if and only if some of its poles has an imaginery part? I am not sure how to apply it to the discrete case though.

Comment: Yes, I know it. I'm not sure if we can apply that to discrete-time.

Comment: In this case, we know that that system has an overshoot (because there are complex eigenvalues), but the overshoot occurs in a sample far away. I just want something like: if it is far away, I will consider with no overshoot, but in that case, I need a way to identify that kind of systems.

Comment: @Zeekless "... a linear system in continuous time has an overshoot if and only if some of its poles has an imaginery part". This is only true for 2nd order systems with no zeros! Check the system $G(s)=\frac{5}{(s^2 + 4 s + 5) (s + 1)}$ for example. Thiago Cavalcante you need to give the zero locations also to calculate the overshoot, since they too affect the overshoot behaviour.

Comment: @obareey Thank you! What about this statement: If a stable continuous time system has no zeros and there is a pair of poles $s_{1,2}$ with nonzero imaginery part such that $\operatorname{Re}(s_{1,2}) > s_k$ for all pure real poles $s_k$ then there will be an overshoot. Is this one true?

Comment: @Zeekless It feels right but I don't have a rigorous proof. Maybe you should ask this as a separate question.